# Linden Scripting Language Weird Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, linden-scripting-language

Can anyone enlight me what is the syntax error in this script? It says `(54,8) Syntax error` which is the last bracket. How on the earth last bracket is syntax error?

```
vector startPosition;
float groundLevel;

default 
{
    state_entry() 
    { 
       // get permission to take over the avatar's control inputs.
       llRequestPermissions( llGetOwner(), PERMISSION_TAKE_CONTROLS );

       startPosition = llGetPos();
       groundLevel = llGround( startPosition );
    }

    run_time_permissions( integer perm )  // event for processing 
                                          // permission dialog.
    {
        if ( perm & PERMISSION_TAKE_CONTROLS )  // permission has been given.
        { 
            // go ahead and take over the forward and backward controls.
            llTakeControls( CONTROL_FWD | CONTROL_BACK | CONTROL_LEFT | CONTROL_RIGHT, TRUE, FALSE ); 
        }
    }

    control( key id, integer held, integer change )  // event for processing 
                                                     // key press.
    { 
        vector position = llGetPos();

        if ( change & held & CONTROL_FWD ) 
        {   // the "move forward" control has been activated.
            if( position.y < (startPosition.y + 10.0) )
            {
               llSetPos( llGetPos() + < 0, 0.5,0>); // move up
            }
        } 
        else if ( change & held & CONTROL_BACK ) 
        {   // the "move backward" key has been activated.
            if( position.y > groundLevel + 1.0 ) 
            {
               llSetPos( llGetPos() + < 0,-0.5,0>); // move down
            }
        }
         if ( change & held & CONTROL_RIGHT)   {   // the "move forward" control has been activated.
            if( position.x < (startPosition.x + 10.0) )
            {
               llSetPos( llGetPos() + < 0.5,0,0>);
            }
        } 
        else if ( change & held & CONTROL_LEFT)
        {
            if( position.y > groundLevel + 1.0 ) 
            {
               llSetPos( llGetPos() + < -0.5,0,0>);            }
        }
```

Comment: Is that the whole script? Looks like the end is cut off.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the whole script, you are missing the closing brackets for both the control event and the default state.

By the way:

1. Your formatting is inconsistent. Choose a style and stick with it, and things like this will be more noticeable.
2. I don't know what viewer you're using, but in Firestorm, compiling your script without the missing brackets gave me the message:

   ```
   (54,10) mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '}'
   1 syntax error(s)
   ```

which is rather more helpful than just a syntax error.